# grails 2.0:  g:field tag,  HTML5 Scaffolding Browser Dependency?

Tags: grails

Grails 2.0 Documentation states: "There is a new HTML5-based scaffolding UI", but then doesn't elaborate on what the implication of this is (that I could find).   Unfortunately the new g:field tag that is used in the scaffolding is not documented as of yet (that I could find).

Do you know / can you comment on the browser dependencies related to using Grail 2.0 HTML5 Scaffolding, in terms of which browser versions one needs to use for Internet Explorer, Firefox and Chrome?  Are there any particular issues/usages to be careful of?

Thanks

P.S.  If you know of where there is documentation on either of these (g:field or html5 implication), please let me know.

Comment: You should clarify your question.  It isn't clear what you are asking.  Remember, SO is based on clear, specific questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the force, read the source! :)

```
Closure field = { attrs ->
    fieldImpl(out, attrs)
}

def fieldImpl(out, attrs) {
    resolveAttributes(attrs)
    attrs.id = attrs.id ?: attrs.name
    out << "<input type=\"${attrs.remove('type')}\" "
    outputAttributes(attrs, out)
    out << "/>"
}
```

So basically it translates into a html5 'INPUT' tag.

Comment: Linking to the source would help others follow your advice. Could you perhaps add a link to where you found this code snippet?

Comment: Hehe, what did you expect ;) ?